# Filter method on another method?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, filter

I want to run a filter method on the renderTable method that I've defined below. Is it possible to do:

`renderTable().filter(x => x.name)`?

Right now, I have a table with rows of each category and their results from a url that provided some json data.

I would like to make a feature that allows users to adjust the setting to return their desired results.

**CODE**

```
const renderTable = () => {
 return players.map(player => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{player.name}</td>
      <td>{player.age}</td>
      <td>{player.gender}</td>
      <td>{player.state}</td>
      <td>{player.status}</td>
    </tr>
   )
 })
}

return (
 <div className = "App">
  <h1>Players</h1>
   <table id = "players">
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>State</th>
       <th>Status</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>{renderTable()}</tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
);
```

Comment: It is, if your `renderTable` method returns an array. But I'm pretty sure it returns `jsx`. So in that case, you should apply the filter right inside the `renderTable` method.

Comment: @SiddAjmera so it would be this `}).filter....` inside the renderTable method?

Comment: Yeah I mean the `enderTable` method would return some `rows`. The row will be populated with some data that would probably come from an array. You can apply a filter on that array right before you map that array to `tr`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the filter before the map. Here, give this a try:

```
const renderTable = () => {
  return players
    .filter(player => player.state === "NSW")
    .map(player => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{player.name}</td>
          <td>{player.age}</td>
          <td>{player.gender}</td>
          <td>{player.state}</td>
          <td>{player.status}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
};
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/apply-filter-on-an-array-354r0) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just filter before map `players.filters(...).map`. But this is better

```
const renderTable = () => {
  const rows = []
  players.forEach((player, index) => {
    if(player.name) {
      rows.push(
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{player.name}</td>
          <td>{player.age}</td>
          <td>{player.gender}</td>
          <td>{player.state}</td>
          <td>{player.status}</td>
        </tr>
     )
    }
  })

  return rows;
}
```

Comment: appreciate it but this does not change my table in any way from what I wrote previously codewise. I'm also looking for not just name, but a way for a user to be able to adjust what they want returned

Comment: I think you just change condition `if(player.name) ` to whatever you want